# Average over Grouped By Ids given an interval to Create new File

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, grouping, average

I have a 3D dataset (Easting(X), Northing(Y), Elevation(Z)) and have values for certain deleterious elements that we can call say A, B, C.  The intervals are every 20 feet unless at the end of the Z value then it could be smaller since its not guaranteed you would have even number of 20s.

| ID | midX | midY | midZ | From | To | Length | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 37710.9 | 102978.3 | 5727.2 | 40.0 | 60.0 | 20.0 | 0.284 | 7.5 | 0.010 |
| AAA1 | 37697.7 | 102971.9 | 5713.5 | 60.0 | 80.0 | 20.0 | 0.051 | 2.4 | 0.005 |
| AAA1 | 37684.6 | 102978.3 | 5708.2 | 80.0 | 100.0 | 20.0 | 0.284 | 7.5 | 0.010 |
| AAA1 | 37684.6 | 102970.0 | 5694.5 | 100.0 | 120.0 | 20.0 | 0.153 | 6.5 | 0.150 |
| AAA1 | 37684.6 | 102980.4 | 5683.8 | 120.0 | 140.0 | 20.0 | 0.648 | 5.4 | 0.222 |
| AAA2 | 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5763.0 | 0.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 | 0.051 | 2.1 | 0.045 |
| AAA2 | 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5743.0 | 20.0 | 40.0 | 20.0 | 0.145 | 8.4 | 0.111 |
| AAA2 | 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5723.0 | 40.0 | 58.7 | 18.7 | 0.742 | 0.4 | 0.043 |

I want to take this dataset and make a new dataset that is averaged on the 40s instead of 20s.  If there isn't a pair, then just put the last value.  It averages by ID.  For example would look like this.

| ID | midX | midY | midZ | From | To | Length | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 37704.3 | 102975.1 | 5720.35 | 40.0 | 80.0 | 40.0 | 0.1675 | 4.95 | 0.0075 |
| AAA1 | 37684.6 | 102974.2 | 5701.35 | 80.0 | 120.0 | 40.0 | 0.2185 | 7.0 | 0.080 |
| AAA1 | 37684.6 | 102980.4 | 5683.8 | 120.0 | 140.0 | 20.0 | 0.648 | 5.4 | 0.222 |
| AAA2 | 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5753.0 | 0.0 | 40.0 | 40.0 | 0.098 | 5.25 | 0.078 |
| AAA2 | 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5723.0 | 40.0 | 58.7 | 18.7 | 0.742 | 0.4 | 0.043 |

```
import pandas as  pd
phx =  pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
phx = phx.sort_values(['ID','midZ'],ascending=False).groupby('ID').head(3)
```

This sorts it by ID and descending midZ which is what I need.  The next step is to average in step = 2 but if there is an odd amount, then just keep the last one.  I've been googling and trying various things but its not working.  I tried this:

```
step = 2
phxdf = phx.groupby(phx.index//step).mean()
```

But that didn't give me what I needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  TIA!

Comment: What do you mean by 'averaged on the 40s'.

Comment: I want 40 foot intervals so take 2 20's down the hole and average them into a 40 foot run.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calculating a pseudo grouping column conditional on multiples of 40 after `cumsum()` of `Length` with `numpy.ceil` for upper multiple. Then, run `mean` aggregation with `groupby()` alongside `ID`:

**Data**

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

txt = '''ID|midX|midY|midZ|From|To|Length|A|B|C
AAA1| 37710.9 | 102978.3 | 5727.2 | 40.0  | 60.0  | 20.0   | 0.284 | 7.5 | 0.010 
AAA1| 37697.7 | 102971.9 | 5713.5 | 60.0  | 80.0  | 20.0   | 0.051 | 2.4 | 0.005 
AAA1| 37684.6 | 102978.3 | 5708.2 | 80.0  | 100.0 | 20.0   | 0.284 | 7.5 | 0.010 
AAA1| 37684.6 | 102970.0 | 5694.5 | 100.0 | 120.0 | 20.0   | 0.153 | 6.5 | 0.150 
AAA1| 37684.6 | 102980.4 | 5683.8 | 120.0 | 140.0 | 20.0   | 0.648 | 5.4 | 0.222 
AAA2| 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5763.0 |  0.0  | 20.0  | 20.0   | 0.051 | 2.1 | 0.045 
AAA2| 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5743.0 | 20.0  | 40.0  | 20.0   | 0.145 | 8.4 | 0.111 
AAA2| 36979.0 | 106198.0 | 5723.0 | 40.0  | 58.7  | 18.7   | 0.742 | 0.4 | 0.043'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="|")
```

**Aggregation**

```py
df['grp_40'] = np.ceil(df.groupby(['ID'])['Length'].cumsum().div(40))
df['Length'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'grp_40'])['Length'].transform('sum')

agg = (df.groupby(['ID', 'grp_40'], sort=False, as_index=False)
         .mean()
         .drop('grp_40', axis='columns')
      )

print(agg)
#      ID     midX       midY     midZ   From     To  Length       A     B       C
# 0  AAA1  37704.3  102975.10  5720.35   50.0   70.0    40.0  0.1675  4.95  0.0075
# 1  AAA1  37684.6  102974.15  5701.35   90.0  110.0    40.0  0.2185  7.00  0.0800
# 2  AAA1  37684.6  102980.40  5683.80  120.0  140.0    20.0  0.6480  5.40  0.2220
# 3  AAA2  36979.0  106198.00  5753.00   10.0   30.0    40.0  0.0980  5.25  0.0780
# 4  AAA2  36979.0  106198.00  5723.00   40.0   58.7    18.7  0.7420  0.40  0.0430
```

Comment: Let me try this and I'll get back to you.  Thank you!

Comment: This works when its always 2 repeated IDs but what if you have it where AAA1 has 25 rows and AAA2 has 12 rows, etc.?

Comment: when I remove the .head(3) from my code, it breaks:  AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I added a few more lines. @Parfait

Comment: ah I didn't notice, Just tried it, seems to work.  Thank you!!!!